# Converting std::vector to array an then p/Invoking it causes a Access Violation Exception in mscorlib.dll during marshalling

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, vector, pinvoke

In C++ I have the following struct from 3rd-party code:

```
typedef struct NodeInfoTag
{
    long lResult;
    int bComplete;
    char *pszNodeAddr;
    char *pszParentAddr;
    RTS_WCHAR *pwszNodeName;
    RTS_WCHAR *pwszDeviceName;
    RTS_WCHAR *pwszVendorName;
    unsigned long ulTargetType; 
    unsigned long ulTargetId;
    unsigned long ulTargetVersion;
    unsigned short wMaxChannels;
}NodeInfotyp;
```

And the definition to RTS_WCHAR:

```
#   ifndef RTS_WCHAR_DEFINED
#       define RTS_WCHAR_DEFINED
        typedef wchar_t RTS_WCHAR;  /* wide character value */
#   endif
```

(So it's basically a wchar_t)

Then I have my own class called `CScanNetworkCallback`, which extends the `CPLCHandlerCallback` class, a class from the same vendor:

**.h file:**

```
class CScanNetworkCallback : public CPLCHandlerCallback
{
    public:
        bool bScanComplete;
        NodeInfotyp* pNodeInfo;
        NodeInfotyp* pNodeInfoList;
        std::vector<NodeInfotyp> vList;
        CScanNetworkCallback();
        virtual ~CScanNetworkCallback(void);

        virtual long Notify(CPLCHandler *pPlcHandler, CallbackAddInfoTag CallbackAdditionalInfo);
};
```

The implementation follows their own guidelines with some of my own stuff thrown in:

```
CScanNetworkCallback::CScanNetworkCallback(void) : CPLCHandlerCallback()
{
    bScanComplete = false;
}

CScanNetworkCallback::~CScanNetworkCallback()
{
    delete pNodeInfo;
    delete pNodeInfoList;
}

long CScanNetworkCallback::Notify(CPLCHandler *pPlcHandler, CallbackAddInfoTag CallbackAdditionalInfo)
{
    if (pPlcHandler != NULL)
    {
        if (CallbackAdditionalInfo.ulType == PLCH_SCAN_NETWORK_CALLBACK)
        {
            pNodeInfo = CallbackAdditionalInfo.AddInf.pNodeInfo;
            if (pNodeInfo->lResult == RESULT_OK)
            {
                vList.push_back(*pNodeInfo);
                bScanComplete = false;
            }
            else 
            {
                pNodeInfoList = &vList[0]; //New pointer points to the vector elements, which will be used as an array later on

                // I have also tried copying it, to the same result:
                //std::copy(vList.begin(), vList.end(), pNodeInfoList);

                bScanComplete = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return RESULT_OK;
}
```

So basically, the `Notify` method in the class above is called every time a "node" is found in the network, assigning the node's information to pNodeInfo (please disregard what a node is, it isn't relevant ATM). Since it is called to every node in the network during the scanning process and I must send this information to C++, I couldn't find any other way to do so other than using a `std::vector` to store every callback info for latter use, as I don't know how many nodes there will be at compile time. The `else` part is called after all nodes have been found. In order to make sense out of the C# code, I must describe the implementation of some other C++ methods that are p/Invoked:

```
PROASADLL __declspec(dllexport) void scanNetwork(){
    pScanHandler->ScanNetwork(NULL, &scanNetworkCallback);
}
```

The object `scanNetworkCallback` is static. `pScanHandler` is a pointer to another class from the 3rd party vendor and its `ScanNetwork` method runs on a separate thread. Internally (and I only know that due to this API Guidelines, I don't have its source code), it calls the `Notify` method whenever a node is found in the network, or something to that effect

And finally:

```
PROASADLL __declspec(dllexport) NodeInfotyp* getScanResult(int* piSize) {
    *piSize = scanNetworkCallback.vList.size();
    return scanNetworkCallback.pNodeInfoList;
}
```

That returns the pointer that points to all nodes' information and the amount in as an out parameter. Now let's take a look at the C# code:

```
    public static List<NodeInfoTag> AsaScanNetworkAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SCANNING NETWORK");
        scanNetwork(); // C++ Method

        while (!isScanComplete()) // Holds the C# thread until the scan is complete
            Thread.Sleep(50);

        int size = 0;
        IntPtr pointer = getScanResult(out size); // works fine, I get some IntPtr and the correct size
        List<NodeInfoTag> list = Marshaller.MarshalPointerToList<NodeInfoTag>(pointer, size); // PROBLEM!!!

        // Continue doing stuff
    }
```

This is the class `NodeInfoTag`, to match the C++ NodeInfotyp struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class NodeInfoTag
{
    public int Result;
    public int Complete;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] //char*
    public string NodeAddress; 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] //char*
    public string ParentAddress;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] //wchar_t
    public string VendorName;
    public uint TargetType;
    public uint TargetId;
    public uint TargetVersion;
    public short MaxChannels;
}
```

And this is where I get my Memory Access Violation:

```
internal class Marshaller
{
    public static List<T> MarshalPointerToList<T>(IntPtr pointer, int size)
    {
        if (size == 0)
            return null;

        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        var symbolSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            var current = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, typeof(T));
            list.Add(current);
            pointer = new IntPtr(pointer.ToInt32() + symbolSize);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

The error occurs specifically when marshaling should take place, at the line `var current = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointer, typeof(T));`. This C# code used to work just fine, but the C++ part was terrible, convoluted and error-prone, so I decided to make things more simple but I can't figure out for the life of me why I'm getting this Exception as I'm making sure that all C++ resources are available for C#, since for testing purposes, I don't delete anything in C++ and I'm only using variables with global scope within the class, which is allocated to static memory. So, what did I miss?

**Edit:** I removed `pNodeInfoList = &vList[0];` and rewrote `getScanResult` as follows:

```
static NodeInfotyp pNodeInfoList;

//(...)

PROASADLL __declspec(dllexport) NodeInfotyp* getScanResult(int* piSize) {
    *piSize = scanNetworkCallback.vList.size();
    std::move(scanNetworkCallback.vList.begin(), 
scanNetworkCallback.vList.end(), &pNodeInfoList);
    return &pNodeInfoList;
}
```

No dice. I don't use `new` or `malloc` in any of the variables involved, and even changed pNodeInfoList (the array) from a class member to a global variable. Also, I'm using `move`, as I've been told, could be used to solve ownership problems. Any other tips?

Comment: Because that would take a long time...

Comment: This library has been under development for over one year and overall, it is pretty complex, there's no way I'd rewrite the whole thing it just to iron out some bugs. Or, as it happens in this case, I'm just trying to make a method more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Ownership is not part of the naive C++ type system, so you will not get an error when you delete a pointer you do not own or transfer ownership away without giving it up.

However, semantically certain values and pointers and data blocks are owned by certain types or values.

In this case the vector owns its block of memory.  There is no way to ask it or make it give up ownership.

Calling `.data()` onky provides you a pointer, it does *not* give that pointer semantic ownership.

You store the return value of `.data()` in a member variable.  You later call `delete` on that member variable.  This indicates to me that member variable is supposed to own its data.  So you double delete (as both the vector and the pointer think they own the data pointed to), and your compiler crashes the program for you.

You need to rewite your code taking into account liefetime and ownership of every block of memory you are working with.  One approach is to never ever call new, malloc or delete or free directly, and always use memory managing types like vector and unique ptr.  Avoid persisting raw pointers, as their ownership semantics are not clear from the type.

Comment: @S.O.  I have no idea how your edit is related to my comments.  The new code appears to be copying over random uninitialized memory.